# c# - sql - Call web service from sql

Tags: c#, sql

I want to create a stored procedure that will be called every time a new customer address is added.

It will call the google reverse geocoding web service , pass it the address, and retrieve the coordinates. I will then update the address latitude and longitude attributes from the resulting json extract of these fields.

Example reverse geocoding link

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View+CA

Is this possible all in sql or would I have to create a script?

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: you would need to call the service from something other than sql.  how will the address be added to your database?  it's possible that the address lookup could be done in that code.

Comment: Through a user interface. I had tunnel vision on creating it in SQL but it seems like the best route would be to find the latitude and longitude after the user saves a newly created address and insert it with the address. Do you know if there is any c# library already included that will retrieve the JSON response from the web request? Thanks man

Comment: Not that I know of.  Most of the implementations I've seen [use JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).  If you take that approach, you could do the lookup before the data is saved to the database, which may be a better approach because then you would know if the user entered a bad address before you save it.  You could then re-prompt the user to correct the unrecognized address.

Comment: To clarify:  You could do it from C#.  I'm just saying I usually see it in JavaScript so it's more interactive with the user.

Comment: That's a great idea. Thank you Devlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to handle your service call outside of SQL.  You could do it from C#, but you'll have a more interactive experience for your user if you do it from JavaScript because then you can have the user correct a bad address immediately before sending the data to your server to be saved to the database.

The Google Geocoding documentation is here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

You're looking for the Lat/Long lookup.

Comment: devlin, any suggestions to checking for a bad address that's not making sure that results are coming back. It seems like it will return latitudes and longitudes if it even recognizes a state and country in the address

Comment: you can look for the location_type.  So, for example, if the results return with location_type = APPROXIMATE, you would ask your user to correct the address.